# Writing unit testcase for a checkbox with reactt testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing

```
const CheckBox = (props) => {
    const { className, active = false, onClick = () => { }, label = '', isHidden=false } = props;
    if(isHidden) return null;
    return <StyledCheckBox className={className} onClick={() => onClick(!active)} >
        <div data-testid="CHECKBOX_ID" className={`box ${active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}`}>
            {active && <div className='check-mark' />}
        </div>
        <div className='label'>{label}</div>
    </StyledCheckBox>
}
```

how should i write test case for this if i have to see if the checkbox is selected or not?

Answer (score 0):

So I would do it like so; assert it exists, assert it's initially unchecked, create click event, assert its selected by asserting check-mark div appears.

```
it('test case example', () => {
   const { getByTestId, getByRole, container } = render(<CheckBox {...props} />)
   const activeDiv = container.querySelector('.check-mark') // get div
   expect(activeDiv).toBeFalsy() // assert doesn't exist when un-checked
   expect(getByTestId('CHECKBOX_ID')) // assert checkbox comp exists
   expect(getByRole('checkbox')).not.toBeChecked() // assert it isn't checked
   userEvent.click(getByRole('checkbox')) // click the checkbox
   expect(getByRole('checkbox')).toBeChecked() // assert it is checked
   expect(activeDiv).toBeTruthy() // assert div shows after active
})
```

Does this help?

Comment: this looks good but I am getting error that "className" prop is not defined so do I need to create a mock fn for <StyledCheckBox> as well as for onclick fn ????

Comment: for example: const CrossIcon = ({ className, onClick, background, isHidden=false, }) => {
    if(isHidden) return null
    return <StyledCrossIcon className={className} onClick={onClick} background={background}>
        <span className="bar-1" />
        <span className="bar-2" />
    </StyledCrossIcon>
}

Comment: you're passing className as a prop, have you passed this to the test component? within ...props?

Comment: yes like this/..... const props = { className } and then render(<CheckBox {...props} />)

Comment: you're not giving it a value? Would be much easier if you could link this to a sandbox or something

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-cookies-9mz8l

Comment: i have mentioned the error too

Comment: I had a look at the sandbox, you've not exported StyledCheckBox from anywhere so therefore it can't render the checkbox. Please update your styles for it

Comment: it is still getting the same error "Unable to find an accessible element with the role "checkbox". this this dom tree <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="css-1saz8t6"
        >
          <div
            class="box inactive"
            data-testid="CHECKBOX_ID"
          />
          <div
            class="label"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

Comment: can we not use anything else apart from getByRole ??

Comment: why are you not using input type checkbox and label label the checkbox in your html?

Comment: we have created fn

Comment: I just want to change my classname propert to "box active" from "box inactive" and vice versa. but everytime I do fireEvent.click its not changing my property so kindly help me in solving that issue

Comment: ok if you're not using checkbox element then getByRole won't work. You can use getByTestId and grab the element with the data-testid. Or you could use .querySelector('element') to grab any you want if necessary. With your onClick, would be easier to investigate if you could update your sandbox to replicate what you have, currently it doesn't work so it's hard to understand your issue